# get size of all shared memory segments

Tags: c++, c, solaris, shared-memory

On Solaris it is possible to get with shmctl the size of a shared memory segment that I did not created and for which I don't have the permission ?

For example I want to get the size of a segment created by another user with read-only mode for him only (600).

I tried with the code below to get total size of all shared memory segments but I get a permission denied

> Cannot access shared memory information for segment 0 because Permission denied

when I don't have read rights on a segment.

```
int *ids = NULL;
uint_t nids = 0;
uint_t n;

unsigned long memoryUsed = 0;

if (shmids(ids, nids, &n) != 0)
{
   cout <<  "Failed to get shared memory info: " << strerror(errno);
   return 0;
}

nids =n;
ids = (int *) realloc(ids, nids * sizeof (int));

if (shmids(ids, nids, &n) != 0)
{
    cout <<  "Failed to get shared memory info: " << strerror(errno);
    return 0;
}
else
{    

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        struct shmid_ds buf;
        int iError = shmctl(ids[i], IPC_STAT, &buf);
        if( iError < 0 )
        {
           cout << "Cannot access shared memory information for segment " << ids[i] << " because " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        } 
        else
        {
            memoryUsed += buf.shm_segsz;
        }
    }    
}

return memoryUsed;
```

I ask the question because ipcs -ma command is able to get the size of all existing segments therefore I should be able to do the same.

```
IPC status from <running system> as of Wed Mar  9 19:44:34 MET 2016
T         ID      KEY        MODE        OWNER    GROUP  CREATOR   CGROUP NATTCH      SEGSZ  CPID  LPID   ATIME    DTIME    CTIME
Shared Memory:
m        215   0          --rw-------  olivier    staff   olivier  staff      0       4096 10869 10869 19:10:21 19:10:21 19:10:21
m          0   0x8d0c6ee7 --rw-------  oracle     dba     oracle   dba        4 40956239872   785  2275  7:17:38  7:17:38  7:16:47
```

Comment: At first you said the segment has "read-only mode for him only", then you said "when I have read rights on a segment". Which is it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code of `ipcs` to see how it does it?

Comment: Just run `truss ipcs` - it will tell you exactly how it did call `shmctl`.

Comment: Or you can look here:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/ipcs/ipcs.c#268

Comment: @Barmar I corrected it.

Comment: It looks like `shmctl` works essentially the same as your code, except it uses `shmctl64` with the flag `IPC_STAT64`. But if it gets an error, it simply skips that ID, it doesn't print the error message.

Comment: yes I will test with iError < 0 instead of iError != 0

Comment: I tested with iError < 0, I stil have the same behavior: error message Permission denied. It is normal according to shmctl man : `EACCES The cmd  argument  is  equal  to  IPC_STAT  and  {READ}  operation  permission  is denied to the calling process.`

Comment: @SergeyA When I run `truss ipc -m` I have these calls: `shmids(0x00000000, 0, 0x08047610) shmids(0x08066468, 17, 0x08047610) write(1, " T                   I D".., 56) write(1, " S h a r e d   M e m o r".., 15) shmctl(83886104, IPC_STAT64, 0x08047560) getuid() mmap(0x00010000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGN, -1, 0) getuid() getuid() open64("/var/run/name_service_door", O_RDONLY) fcntl(3, F_SETFD, 0x00000001) door_info(3, 0xFEF7F4C4) door_call(3, 0x08046EC8) brk(0x08066980) brk(0x0806A980) ... ` I  will try to use door service.

Comment: The door service calls are to look up the UID and GID of the user/group.

Comment: I'm trying to test IPC_STAT64 instead of IPC_STAT, do you know which header I should include ?

Comment: I found that I need to include `<sys/ipc_impl.h>` and it is working ! With shmctl64 and IPC_STAT64 I can get all segments sizes even if I don't have read rights , perhaps it is a bug in shmctl64 ? in my example the segment of oracle user is big I tried with a small segment and I have the same behavior : shmctl is not able to retrieve segment size, shmctl64 is able to retrieve segment size.

Comment: @olivier, I doubt it's a bug :)

Comment: @SergeyA I don't find any documentation on shmctl64 for Solaris. (information I get is for IBM i https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/ipcshmct64.htm) Do you think it is an enhancement instead of a bug ? For me it looks like a kind of security breache. On Linux when I run  ipcs -m with my user it doesn't display read only shared memory segments created by root.

Comment: @olivier, you can take it up to Oracle Support if you must :)

Comment: @SergeyA they answer me that I should not use shmctl64.