# Get size of mmaped shared memory

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap

I'm debugging some odd fails with reading from shared memory, and for debugging purposes I'd like to put some prints that show me currently `mmap`ed size. So, for example, I have this code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, void*> make_shm() {
    const int shm = shm_open("foo", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRWXO | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXU);
    if (shm == -1) {
        perror("connect_to_shm: shm_open failed");
        return {-1, nullptr};
    }

    void* shm_ptr = mmap(nullptr, 15360000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);
    if (shm_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("connect_to_shm: mmap failed");
        close(shm);
        return {-1, nullptr};
    }
    return {shm, shm_ptr};
}

int main() {
    auto [shm, shm_ptr] = make_shm();
    // how do I print the mmapped size?
}
```

How do I derive the `15360000` size from the `shm` and `shm_ptr`?

I tried searching, but all results I'm getting for "get size of shared memory" are either about memory limits, or about sizes of pages. The closest I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900144/get-size-of-all-shared-memory-segments), but it's for Solaris and unanswered anyway.

Comment: @DrosvarG I specifically didn't add any language tags, because the question is not specific to a language. The testcase here is just for reference, the question is about API.

Comment: Alright my bad, as I saw a c++ example, I supposed that adding the tag may bring people who might have already used it on this question, which could have provide you more answers. Also I misunderstood the fact that it wasn't a c++ question

Comment: Ok, so, I don't care ATM enough to write code for the actual answer, but one solution I found comes down to 3 steps: 1. get from file descriptor the actual name it points to *(it can be done with `/proc/$pid/fd`)*, 2. Find in `/proc/$pid/map_files/` directory the symlink that points to the name you got in step 1, 3. now, all symlinks there named as `start_offset-past_end_offset`, so all you need is to convert this name to actual digits, and then substract `start` from `past_end`.